# How to retrieve nested data in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

working with OpenJPA2 persistence. I have a very simple entity class, that does have a String property and a List property. I do persist its instances flawlessly with the nested List (in a JSF2 web project). I check the database and there appears two tables (I use automatic schema generation), one for the entity itself, and other table for the nested List. All data persisted using EntityManager is stored fine on both tables.

Problem is I cannot retrieve nested data. I mean, I do a Query for getting all instances of the entity, but the List of all instances come empty.

(DB Engine is MySQL. ORM is OpenJPA2. Server is TomEE 1.6. IDE is Netbeans 8. I use automatic schema generation, so I DO NOT WANT to design the database tables, and I DO WANT to let the ORM create the tables, so I can work purely with objects and forget about DB.)

following is Entity Class code:

```
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

   // getters and setters omitted for brevity.
```

It does have an associated Facade Class, which is ClienteFacade. It includes the getAll method which uses a JPQL Query.

```
public List<Cliente> listaClientes(){
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Cliente c");
        return query.getResultList(); }
```

Problem is, I get all instances of the entity in a List, but all lists of List emails come out empty. I think problem may be in the JPQL query. Still trying to learn JPQL with some difficulty... so please, How can I retrieve the nested data with JPQL?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` because the default type is lazy. That means that the lists are not loaded directly.